# What is the difference between Local and External Parameter Names in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

```
struct Celsius {
    var temperatureInCelsius: Double
    init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
    }
}


let boilingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
// boilingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 100.0
let freezingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromKelvin: 273.15)
// freezingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 0.0
```

I'm confused why the init functions have (fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) and (fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double). The docs say:

> "The first initializer has a single initialization parameter with an external name of from Fahrenheit and a local name of fahrenheit. The second initializer has a single initialization parameter with an external name of from Kelvin and a local name of kelvin."

Why do we need so many names?

Comment: I've just written a Swift tutorial that covers this. It might help you! Internal parameter names: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_parameters_and_return_value External parameter names: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_external_parameter_names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This is used for an easy interface with `Objective C`. `Objective C`
   methods have both named  local parameters and external parameters.

   For example this is a typical `Objective C` method.

   ```
   -(void)setValue:(NSObject *)object forKey:(NSObject *)key
   ```

   This will be called as `[dict setValue:object1 forKey:object2]`

   The same function in swift will be called as

   ```
   dict.setValue(object1,forKey:object2)
   ```
2. It also clarifies the purpose of each parameter and helps in distinguishing functions with similar names and different parameters. Functions can also have same signature with different external names.

   ```
   init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
       temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
   }
   init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
       temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
   }
   ```

   In your example, both functions take a `Double`. Without external parameters there will be no way to distinguish them when called.

Answer (score 2):

Local parameter is used in your method,while external parameter is used when you call the method.